# AngularJS reference factory.function from external module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two distinct application files for angularjs defined below:

search.js

```
var app = angular.module('search',['ngGrid']);
    app.factory('answers',function($http){  
        return{  
           search: function(params,success,error){  
            //code to execute over rest    
         },  
            otherSearch: function(params,success,error){  
            //code to execute over rest    
         }
        };  
});
```

results.js

```
var app = angular.module('results',['ui.bootstrap','ngGrid']);  
    app.controller('resultsCtrl',function($scope,$http,search) // search should reference search.js  
    search.search();  
    search.otherSearch();
```

});

What I am trying to do is reference the `search` and `otherSearch` functions within `search.js` from `results.js` however, this is failing with unknown provider when I do this:

```
var app = angular.module('results',['ui.bootstrap','ngGrid','search']);
```

what is the correct way to make it so I can invoke `FACTORY` methods that are contained within `search.js`

Comment: it looks like you are actually naming the factory `answers`.. Have you tried injecting `answers` and referencing it that way instead of `search`?

Comment: @Jakemmarsh not sure I follow, can you provide a solution below so I can see a minimal example of what you mean?  Also, this would work fine if it was all in the same file, but i am reusing my code.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, all you are doing is re-declaring your Angular app with the name `search`:

```
var app = angular.module('search',['ngGrid']);
```

It is in this code below that you're actually declaring the factory, and you've named it `answers`:

```
    app.factory('answers',function($http){  
        return{  
           search: function(params,success,error){  
            //code to execute over rest    
         },  
            otherSearch: function(params,success,error){  
            //code to execute over rest    
         }
        };  
});
```

I think the problem is you're trying to inject `answers` as `search`. Try this instead:

```
app.controller('resultsCtrl',function($scope,$http,answers)
    answers.search();  
    answers.otherSearch();
```

Comment: so by making the above change I get:  `Unknown provider answersProviders <- answers`

Comment: So this seems to work if I make it a service (for answers) instead of the factory.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why it only works as a service. Another thing I noticed, though, is that you're defining `app` as two different things: `search` and `results`. Not sure if that's affecting this

Comment: these are two distinct files, so I would have though `var app` was local to that file.  It could potentially be a conflict, if angular does something I am not expecting.